# Discord.py does not want to send mistakes to the console

Tags: python, discord.py

I wrote the code for the output in the error console via `utils.setup_logging`
Errors were derived correctly when I only used this code:

```
discord.utils.setup_logging(level = logging.ERROR, root = False)
discord.utils.setup_logging(level = logging.WARN, root = False)
discord.utils.setup_logging(level = logging.WARNING, root = False)
discord.utils.setup_logging(level = logging.INFO, root = False)
```

All errors displayed such as code synthesis, warning etc.
But today I create a new team and I made a mistake in the code. After checking it, the console would have to derive a mistake, but she did not do it (the team was not fulfilled by itself). I do not know, maybe I really made a mistake in writing the code. But still the console would have to bring out at least some mistake.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from config import settings
import asyncio
import os
import logging
from time import strftime
from time import gmtime
import sqlite3

bot = commands.Bot(settings['prefix'], intents = discord.Intents.all())
bot.remove_command('help')
discord.utils.setup_logging(level = logging.ERROR, root = False)
discord.utils.setup_logging(level = logging.WARN, root = False)
discord.utils.setup_logging(level = logging.WARNING, root = False)
discord.utils.setup_logging(level = logging.INFO, root = False)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} підключився до Discord.')


async def load_extensions():
    """Load cogs for main file
    """
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

async def main():
    await load_extensions()
    await bot.start(settings['token'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

`cogs/test.py`

```py
class test(commands.Cog, name='Інформативні команди'):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    @commands.command()
    async def server(self, ctx):
        snsfwlvl = str(ctx.guild.explicit_content_filter)
        if snsfwlvl == 'all_members':
            snsfwlvl = 'Перевіряти кожного учасника'
        elif snsfwlvl == 'no_role':
            snsfwlvl = 'Перевіряти учасників без ролей'
        elif snsfwlvl == 'disabled':
            snsfwlvl = 'Не встановлено'
        else:
            snsfwlvl = 'Не знайдено'
        
        text_channels = len(ctx.guild.text_channels)
        voice_channels = len(ctx.guild.voice_channels)
        stage_channels = len(ctx.guild.stage_channels)
        total_channels = text_channels + voice_channels + stage_channels
        
        total_members = ctx.guild.members
        online = 0
        idle = 0
        offline = 0
        humans = 0
        bots = 0
        for member in total_members:
            if member.status == 'online':
                online+=1
            if member.status == 'idle':
                idle+=1
            if member.status == 'oflline':
                oflline+=1
            if member.bot is True:
                bot+=1
            if member.bot is False:
               humans+=1
        
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color = settings['color'],
            title = f"Інформація про сервер {ctx.guild.name}"
        )
        
        created_at = ctx.guild.created_at
        
        embed.add_field(
            name = f"Власник сервера", 
            value = f"{ctx.guild.owner.mention}", 
            inline = True
            )
        embed.add_field(
            name = "Id", 
            value = ctx.guild.id, 
            inline = True
            )
        embed.add_field(
            name = "Створений: ", 
            value = strftime("%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S", created_at), 
            inline = True
            )
        embed.add_field(
            name = "Перевірка: ", 
            value = snsfwlvl, 
            inline = True
            )
        embed.add_field(
            name = "Учасники:", 
            value = f"<:total_members:1038376493669154836>Всього: **{total_members}**\n<:members:1038376476870979594>Учасників: **{humans}**\n<:bots:1038376472521482263>Ботів: **{bots}**", 
            inline = True
            )
        embed.add_field(
            name = "Статуси:", 
            value = f"<:ofline:1038376481774120970>Онлайн: **{online}**\n<:idle:1038376474958381056>Відійшли: **{idle}**\n<:ofline:1038376481774120970>Не в мережі: **{offline}**", 
            inline = True
            )
        embed.add_field(
            name = "Канали:", 
            value = f"<:total_channels:1038376491576205375>Всього: **{total_channels}**\n<:text_channels:1038376489399357504>Текстові: **{text_channels}**\n<:voice_channels:1038376495414001724>Голосові: **{voice_channels}**"
            )
        
        embed.set_thumbnail(url = ctx.guild.icon)
        
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently updated my code with `logging`. First of all, after you have imported library, you should give the basic config of your log.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="bot.log", level=logging.INFO, filemode="a")
```

As you saw there are multiple levels of logs, `NOTSET`, `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARNING`, `ERROR` and `CRITICAL`. By stating I want the `level=logging.INFO`, I actually inform my logging process that I wish to collect only INFO+ levels, so I won't take DEBUG or NOSET.

You can also produce a format for your logs, like :

```
logging.basicConfig(filename="BotLog.txt", level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s %(message)s", filemode="a")
```

This will print the time, then the message to log.

What I don't see in your code is the next step, aka calling the log to register an action.

```
async def register (ctx, name) : 
    if name == "" :
        logging.warning ("| BOT : no name argument !")
    else : logging.info ("| BOT : name to register : "+name)
```

So it is your responsability to setup but also call `logging` method. Console will produce error message only if your code is wrong at some point, but if your code is fine, there will be no error. Also, you have to call for functions to actually get errors in. If you code for example :

```
async def returnMessage (ctx) :
    ctx.send (ctx.message)
```

then you'll only get a NoneType error if you call `returnMessage` message function, because `send()` is async and needs an `await`, that interpreter will only consider once in the function.

Comment: Very interesting but nothing is clear

Comment: In short, you have to add by yourself the stuff you wish to log. There is no `logging.info()` or `logging.warning()` or anything else so your log doesn't record stuff at all. Well, almost not at all, since discord.py is using logging methods, you can receive info+ messages from discord.py. But nothing concerning your code.